# jQuery Element On-Screen Visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use the following plugin to determine if an element is visible on the screen and then I want to use a jQuery effect on it:

http://www.teamdf.com/web/194/jquery-element-onscreen-visibility

I am able to get the effect working if the mouse hovers over the region, but now I want the user to experience the effect in the case their mouse doesn't hover over the div region.

Now I have more experience with Java than jQuery so I don't know if the conditional statement works the same way. I have been researching online and all of the plugins don't give an exact example of this so I took a shot in trying it myself in different ways. I am trying to minimize the CSS in this example as well and use only jQuery. Netbeans doesn't give this code an error, but it still doesn't work. Please help me by providing me guidance in this task.. My code is as follows:

```
<script>
if($('#pledge').visible(true)){

    $('#projectone').stop(true, true).fadeIn({ duration: 700, queue: false }).css('display', 'none').slideDown(700);   
    $('#projecttwo').stop(true, true).fadeIn({ duration: 700, queue: false }).css('display', 'none').slideDown(700);
}

else

   {
    $('#projectone').hide("slide",{direction:"left"},1000);
    $('#projecttwo').hide("slide",{direction:"right"},1000);

   }
</script>
```

Comment: Unlike Java's `true` and `false` Boolean values, JavaScript operates with [`truthy` and `falsy`](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) concepts.

Comment: In your first line, try `if($('#pledge').is(':visible')) {...}`. I don't think `.visible()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: are you asking whether it is visible in the common sense or whether it is visible in the viewport(ie if the the user is able to see it or not without scrolling up or down)

Comment: Whether it is visible on the viewport. I want each of the div regions #projectone and #projecttwo to slide in from different directions when the user scrolls down to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery allows you to check if an element is visible or not in the following way

```
$(element).is(":visible")
```

Try,

```
<script>
if($('#pledge').is(":visible")){
    $('#projectone').stop(true, true).fadeIn({ duration: 700, queue: false }).css('display', 'none').slideDown(700);   
    $('#projecttwo').stop(true, true).fadeIn({ duration: 700, queue: false }).css('display', 'none').slideDown(700);
} else  {
    $('#projectone').hide("slide",{direction:"left"},1000);
    $('#projecttwo').hide("slide",{direction:"right"},1000);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: beat me to it, but now that i re-read the question it seems like he's not asking if the element is visible, but instead whether the user is navigated on an area of the screen where they would be able to see the element without scrolling up and down.

Comment: You seem to be using inline JS. Is jQuery included before this? Do you see any JavaScript errors in the browser console?

Comment: All I ended up doing was downloading the javascript plugin and tried using jQuery to make it work. 

Here is the example: http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/examples/demo-basic.html

Comment: Essentially it looks like it may work if I toggle a class with animations in CSS, but I was wondering if I could go ahead and skip the CSS and do it through jQuery effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $(element).css('display') == 'none' ){
       // element is hidden
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.